# input file validation using jquery plugin

Tags: php, jquery, html

this is my code in this code everything working good but file filed is not validating by this code.
all input field is validating by this validation plugin except file type filed.. i think i am missing some thing plz debug it

```js
$("#contactus_form").validate({

    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        name: "required",
        contact: {
          required:true,
          maxlength: 10,
            minlength: 10,
          digits: true

        },
        degree: "required",
        applying_for: "required",
        experience: {
          required:true,
          //  maxlength: 10,
          digits: true

        },
        user_cv: {
          //check:"required",
      required: true,
      extension: "doc|pdf"
    },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }


    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        name: "Please enter your first name",
        contact: "Please enter your contact number",
        degree: "Please enter your Qualification",
        experience: "Please enter your experience",
        user_cv: "Please select Your Cv",
        applying_for: "Please accept our policy",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address"

    },


});
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="contactus_form" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Name*" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Name*'">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Email*" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Email*'">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Contact Number*" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Contact number'">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <!--   <input type="text" id="degree"class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Highest Degree*" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Highest Degree'">
          -->
             <select id="degree" name="degree"   class="form-control">
               <option value="">Not selected </option>
                <option value="Graduation ">Graduation </option>
                  <option value="Post Graduation">Post Graduation  </option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="applying_for" name="applying_for" class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Applying For" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Applying For'">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="experience" name="experience" class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Experince in Year" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Experince in Year'">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="field">
                <input type="file" name="user_cv" id="user_cv" class="inputfile inputfile-6" />
                <label for="user_cv" class="file-upload"> <span class="form-control attach" id="user_cv_name">Upload Resume</span>
                  <strong class="browse-btn butn">Browse</strong></label>
              </div>

             </div>
            <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn-style sub">SUBMIT</button>
          </form>
```

Comment: Where is `validate()` from? Name your library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you forget to add `jquery validate` libraby.

Try this snippet hope it will helps you

**EDIT**

You should add `additional-methods.js` in your code. Check Now it is working properly

```js
$("#contactus_form").validate({

    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        name: "required",
        contact: {
          required:true,
          maxlength: 10,
            minlength: 10,
          digits: true

        },
        degree: "required",
        applying_for: "required",
        experience: {
          required:true,
          //  maxlength: 10,
          digits: true

        },
        user_cv: {
         required: true,
         extension: "doc|pdf"
       },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        name: "Please enter your first name",
        contact: "Please enter your contact number",
        degree: "Please enter your Qualification",
        experience: "Please enter your experience",
        user_cv: "Please select Your Cv",
        applying_for: "Please accept our policy",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address"

    },


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" id="contactus_form" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Name*" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Name*'">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Email*" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Email*'">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Contact Number*" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Contact number'">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <!--   <input type="text" id="degree"class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Highest Degree*" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Highest Degree'">
          -->
             <select id="degree" name="degree"   class="form-control">
               <option value="">Not selected </option>
                <option value="Graduation ">Graduation </option>
                  <option value="Post Graduation">Post Graduation  </option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="applying_for" name="applying_for" class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Applying For" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Applying For'">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="experience" name="experience" class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Experince in Year" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Experince in Year'">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="field">
                <input type="file" name="user_cv" id="user_cv" class="inputfile inputfile-6" />
                <label for="user_cv" class="file-upload"> <span class="form-control attach" id="user_cv_name">Upload Resume</span>
                  <strong class="browse-btn butn">Browse</strong></label>
              </div>

             </div>
            <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn-style sub">SUBMIT</button>
          </form>
```

Comment: @shubhamyadav But it is working properly. which error you get?

Comment: i m not getting any error when i click on submit buttun form is submitted even if no file is selected

Comment: @shubhamyadav answer edited Please check now. I think you also forget to add `additional-methods.js` file

Comment: @shubhamyadav did my answer helps you? Please give feedback. and Please accept it if it is helpful to you. that will also helps me too. :)

Answer (score 1):

**check snippet .its working**

> include external  `jquery.validate.js`  also do not forgot to add `jquery libray`

```js
$("#contactus_form").validate({

    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        name: "required",
        contact: {
          required:true,
          maxlength: 10,
            minlength: 10,
          digits: true

        },
        degree: "required",
        applying_for: "required",
        experience: {
          required:true,
          //  maxlength: 10,
          digits: true

        },
        user_cv: {
          //check:"required",
      required: true,
      extension: "doc|pdf"
    },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }


    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        name: "Please enter your first name",
        contact: "Please enter your contact number",
        degree: "Please enter your Qualification",
        experience: "Please enter your experience",
        user_cv: "Please select Your Cv",
        applying_for: "Please accept our policy",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address"

    },


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" id="contactus_form" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Name*" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Name*'">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Email*" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Email*'">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Contact Number*" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Contact number'">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <!--   <input type="text" id="degree"class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Highest Degree*" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Highest Degree'">
          -->
             <select id="degree" name="degree"   class="form-control">
               <option value="">Not selected </option>
                <option value="Graduation ">Graduation </option>
                  <option value="Post Graduation">Post Graduation  </option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="applying_for" name="applying_for" class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Applying For" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Applying For'">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="experience" name="experience" class="form-control contro" value="" placeholder="Experince in Year" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Experince in Year'">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="field">
                <input type="file" name="user_cv" id="user_cv" class="inputfile inputfile-6" />
                <label for="user_cv" class="file-upload"> <span class="form-control attach" id="user_cv_name">Upload Resume</span>
                  <strong class="browse-btn butn">Browse</strong></label>
              </div>

             </div>
            <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn-style sub">SUBMIT</button>
          </form>
```

Comment: i have added all library

Comment: thank there were no prblm there were  only my designing isssue  btw thanks guys to help me

Answer (score 0):

try this for file validation

```
$('input[name^="fileupload"]').each(function () {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        extension: "doc|pdf"
    })
})
```

Comment: i think there is a only one input `file` type so need to do each loop

Comment: how i can do this?

Comment: Add it in an if loop inside your validate function